# Identify if an activity has just been started

Tags: android

I have 2 activities.

Activity 1 is the 'Homepage' which consists of one spinner.

Activity 2 will be started once an item from the spinner has been selected in Activity 1. The value of the item will also be passed into Activity 2.

Actvity 2 also has the same spinner as Actvity 1.

I would like to make a variable (referenced as `TABLE_NAME` in the code below) whose value will be the selection made in Activity 1 when Activity 2 is initally started but after that the variable value will be the selection made in Activity 2.

Is there an easy way to identify if an activity has just been started?

I've tried to show what I want in the code below:

```
public class MyOnItemSelectedListener implements OnItemSelectedListener {

    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,
        View view, int pos, long id) {          

            if(this activity was just started)
            {Intent sender=getIntent();
        String TABLE_NAME=sender.getExtras().getString("TABLE_NAME");}
            else
            {TABLE_NAME = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();}            


        Cursor cursor = getStats(TABLE_NAME);             

        showStats(cursor);

    }

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
      // Do nothing.
    }
}
```

Comment: What scripting/programming language?

Comment: That edit is not enough. Sure, SQL is what you use for your database, but what language are you using for your application?

Comment: I've updated the edit with some code. Hope this makes more sense!

Comment: Hello, I've approached it differently. I changed the TABLE_NAME variable to be the position of the selection in Activity 1 and then passed that into Activity 2 and used the setSelection method. Thanks for all your efforts to help. It's much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code...

> Intent sender=getIntent(); String
>   TABLE_NAME=sender.getExtras().getString("TABLE_NAME");

... should be moved from your `onItemSelected` selected function, and instead be done in the `onCreate`function of your Activity 2.

And of course, while doing that you must also call your `getStats`/`showStats` after this is done in `onCreate` as well (or preferably, these two should be refactored into a separate function, as you will be calling this both from `onCreate` and `onItemSelected`).

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've added the code to the onCreate method which does call the getStats / showStats method however this only works if I comment out the getStats / showStats code within the onItemSelected method (the emulator crashes otherwise). Any idea why this may happen? Apologies....I'm quite new.

Comment: @Sumino7: that is impossible to say without knowing what happens inside your `getStats`/`showStats` methods. If you have a new problems with these however, you should post this as a _new_ question. Also remember to mark the answer that helped you the most as accepted (there is a check mark to the left of every answer to your question).

Answer (score 0):

If this is within android (which is the tag that is on the post), you can put a hook in the 'onCreate()' method in which you save what activity you are in to the Database table.  The onCreate method is called every time an activity is created/re-created.

```
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //this is where you would identify the activity has been called, perhaps spinning off a thread to handle a database call:)
}
```

Comment: onCreate calls happen on your UI thread. Don't do I/O on your UI thread! You don't have latency guarantees for it and it can make your app unresponsive.

Comment: I was merely attempting to answer the question of, is there an easy way to identify if an activity has just been started?  I agree with you on the point that I/O should not be done inside the UI thread.